# Revolution scroll slider when user doesn't scroll some where

Tags: wordpress, slider, elementor, revolution-slider

hi I want to create a scroll based slider website like this site:
https://le-mugs.com/

what should I do on sliders that when user doesn't scroll, sliders run automatically and be completed?

Comment: Could  you pleasw post you details what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way in elementor that it manages view port and goes to other section(scroll snap).
it is what I want, but when I use it, scrolling slider doesn't show anymore...

Comment: if the you does not found proper answer then add this text as part of question only so other user can help you to find answer.